# how to remove first 2 lines from a .xslx file using unix command?

Tags: excel, linux, unix

file details - /directory/company.xlsx

I wanted to remove the first 2 lines of the above file using a unix command.

I tried using below logic. But after executing the logic, when i try to open the file, it shows a error called "excel file cannot open because the file format or file extension is not valid". But before doing the sed, i was able to open the same file.
 `for f in /directory/company.xlsx;  do  sed -i "1,2d" "$f";  done`

Comment: Err..., you know that a xlsx file is a **binary** file, don't you? In fact, it is a zip archive containing a number of XML files.How can you expect to be able to handle that through a **text** file utility? The best I can imagine is: 1/ convert the file to a csv file with libreoffice(csv is a **text** format), 2/ remove first 2 lines of the csv with sed or ed, 3/ convert back the csv file to xslx. But that will drop any formatting and even column types could be changed. Long story made short: don't, and instead ask for the file to be in a text format.

Comment: Python has module(s) to edit Excel files.  But you cannot do it with basic Unix shell commands.